# gnuplot 5.5: no auto axis limits

Tags: gnuplot

I've installed gnuplot 5.5 from git. Now it doesn't plot with automatic axis limits.
Here is the graph produced with earlier version (5.3 or 5.4):

[image]

And this is plotted with current version:

[image]

Here is the command for this plot:

```
plot [][3.0145:3.5755] 3.04 w filledcurves x1 fc rgb "#d9d9d9" notitle, \
3.55 w filledcurves x2 fc rgb "#d9d9d9" notitle, \
for [i=1:11] 'gpdata.dat' every :::0::0 using 1:i+1 lt i+1 lw 3 ps 1.5 t word(elements,i) w linesp,\
3.04 w lines lw 4 lt 1 lc rgb "red" t 'Допуск',3.55 w lines lw 4 lt 1 lc rgb "red" notitle
```

When I set the limits explicitly: `plot [:35064.46][3.0145:3.5755]` I get this:

[image]

i.e. the end points are hidden.

Is there a way to return previous behavior?

Comment: We don't have your data to directly reproduce it. But I couldn't reproduce it (yet) with some other data. Have you maybe tried `set xrange[:] noextend`? Check `help noextend`.

Comment: @theozh great, now it works as earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the StackOverflow "rules": no answer in the comments...

```
set xrange[:] noextend
```

should avoid the extension of the plotting range to the next "nice" tic. Check `help noextend`.